# How to animate any click event

Tags: jquery

I have written this code to remove an element now I want give any effect to it using jQuery

where I can add animate function to it or any other

```
  $(".close-btn").each(function(element){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
      $(this).closest('div.card').remove();
    }); 
  });
}
```

I have Tried do it like this

```
$(this).closest('div.card').hide('slow').remove();
```

but this didn't worked

Comment: See [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

Comment: You need to be more specific with the type of transition you want to create. The duplicates cover the basic fade/slide techniques, though.